# Is the Spring Boot CGLIB proxy reliable?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-bean, cglib

For a multi-tenant system, I decided that using a proxy in bean definitions would be a logical way to go.

At this point I developed a custom scope. I want to use a proxy. I saw that Spring Boot uses a third party library called CGLIB in ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS method. It is written in the Github repo of this library that there are problems for java 17 and above.

However, as far as I can see, Spring Boot does not directly use this library, it has wrapped it. Is it safe to choose TARGET_CLASS as proxy mode at this point? Is this issue guaranteed by Spring Boot?

Comment: Why *multi-tenant system, I decided that using a proxy in bean definitions*?

Comment: _"Is this issue guaranteed by Spring Boot?"_ Which issue? Please edit your question, providing links, more details and less fuzzy prose. Ideally, also show your code. Like this, the question in not answerable.

Comment: Because I create the beans on a tenant basis, when I change the tenant context in the system and call the proxy object, I only deal with the object belonging to the relevant tenant.

Simply, I'm making a definition as follows.

```@Scope("scopeName"="tenant", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
UserManager userManager;```

Comment: That does not answer my question and does not even seem to be related to your CGLIB question. Please read comments more carefully. You did not provide the information I asked for at all. Please learn how to ask questions and what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is.

Comment: Well, I will try to explain more clearly, for ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, spring boot uses the library named CGLIB.

It says that this library is unmaintained in the Github Repository.

I wanted to prefer TARGET_CLASS as proxyMode. However, when I found out that it was unmaintained, I was skeptical, thinking that it might cause some unclear problems.

And since I don't know how Spring boot uses this library, is it safe to use TARGET_CLASS as proxy mode for Spring Boot even if this library is unmaintained? I wanted to know this.I hope it was more descriptive.

Comment: Firstly, you already said all of that and it still does not answer any of my questions. Secondly, I asked you to update your question, not to quasi repeat it in the comment. Where is your sample project? Was anything unclear about the term [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Did you even read the page I liked to?